# ¿ Por qué el mat-icon no desaparece en Angular?

Tags: angular

cuando el usuario hace el login, mi `componente nav.ts` tiene una variable llamada `username` que recibe el nombre de usuario que hizo `login` con la ayuda del `servicio auth.Service`.
Despues en el `nav.html` pregunto con un `*ngIf` si esa variable `username` es `!= null`, si es correcto que muestre el icono con el nombre de usuario. pero el problema es que si mi `variable username` esta vacia/null, el icono esta siempre visible y no deberia funcionar asi.

Aca `auth.service`

```js
export class AuthService {

  private API = 'http://localhost:4000/admin/login';
  private AUTH_USER = 'http://localhost:4000/api/auth/';

  public username = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');
  public username$ = this.username.asObservable();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private tokenService:TokenService) { }

  loginUser(username: string, password){
    return this.http.post(`${this.AUTH_USER}${'signin/user'}`, {username, password})
    .pipe(
      tap((data: any) => {
        const token = data.token;
        console.log('se guardo el token');
        // aca hacer la variable usernname$ como cart$ en cart.service
        const name = data.username;
        this.username.next(name);
         // guardo el username en localStorage para ser invocada en component main-nav
         localStorage.setItem('username', name);      
        this.tokenService.saveToken(token);
      })
    )
  }

}
```

Aca `nav.ts`

```js
username: string;

  constructor(
    private breakpointObserver: BreakpointObserver,
    private authService: AuthService
    ) {      
        // aca recibo el nombre de usuario con el servicio
       this.authService.username$.subscribe(username => {
         this.username = username;
       });
      
      }

      ngOnInit(): void {
        // si se refresque la pagina, cargo los datos del localStorage para mostrar el username
        // esta localStorage fue creada en auth.service.ts
        if(localStorage.getItem('username') != null){
          this.username = localStorage.getItem('username');
        }

      }
```

Aca `nav.html`

```html
<mat-sidenav-content>
    <mat-toolbar color="primary" class="mat-elevation-z6">
      <button type="button" aria-label="Toggle sidenav" mat-icon-button (click)="drawer.toggle()"
        *ngIf="isHandset$ | async">
        <mat-icon aria-label="Side nav toggle icon">menu</mat-icon>
      </button>
      <mat-icon>eco</mat-icon><span>Bookstore</span>
      
      <!-- ////////// MOSTRANDO EL USERNAME CON EL ICONO ///////////////////////// -->
      <div *ngIf="username != null">
        <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">
          <mat-icon>person_pin</mat-icon>
          {{ username }}
        </button>
        <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
          <a mat-menu-item [routerLink]="'/home'">
            <mat-icon>shopping_cart</mat-icon>
            Mis compras
          </a>
          <a mat-menu-item [routerLink]="'/login'">
            <mat-icon>person_off</mat-icon>
            Cerrar sesión
          </a>
        </mat-menu>
      </div>
    
      <!-- ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// -->
      <div class="spacer"></div>
      <div class="hide">
        <a routerLink="order" class="btn-carrito" mat-raised-button color="warn" [matBadge]="total"
          matBadgeColor="primary">
          <mat-icon class="icon-shopping-cart">shopping_cart</mat-icon>
          Carrito
        </a>
        <!-- <a *ngIf="username != null" mat-list-item routerLink="home">{{ username }}</a> -->
        <a mat-list-item routerLink="home">Home</a>
        <a mat-list-item routerLink="home">Link 2</a>
        <a mat-list-item routerLink="home">Link 3</a>
        <a mat-raised-button color="accent" [routerLink]="'/login'">
          <mat-icon>perm_identity</mat-icon>
          Login
        </a>
      </div>
    </mat-toolbar>
    <!-- Add Content Here -->
    <!-- el router-outlet esta puesto en user-layout.component.html-->
    <!-- <router-outlet></router-outlet> -->
  </mat-sidenav-content>
```

Answer (score 1):

Podrías simplemente evaluar que `username` tenga un valor seteado según su tipo (en este caso, un string):

Primero, al momento de asignar un valor que no se encuentra, el "valor" que se le asigna a `username` es `undefined`. Debido a que la validación sólo considera que `username` sea distinto de `null`, si este es `undefined` se mostrará. Esto puedes confirmarlo ejecutando una validación del tipo:

```js
if (typeof undefined !== typeof null) {
  console.log('undefined es diferente de null');
}
```

Segundo, (esto es opcional) puedes usar un `ng-container` donde describir el `*ngIf` o sólo cambiar la manera en que realizas la validación, lo importante es cómo se declara la misma:

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="username">
  <!-- el contenido que quieres mostrar condicionalmente -->
</ng-container>
```

Conclusiones:

Cuando evalúas que una variable/constante sea "verdadera", en realidad están evaluando varias posibilidades. En el caso de un string, no sólo evalúa que este sea distinto de `undefined` o `null`, sino que también considera el valor "vacío" o `''`

Comment: gracias por responder y por la info!, para solucionarlo simplemente en el div que contiene el icon y username hice esto: <div *ngIf="username">

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado! simplemente cambie el modo de preguntar por la variable `username` en el div que contiene el icono de la siguiente forma:  `<div *ngIf="username">` quedando de esta forma:

```js
<div *ngIf="username">
        <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">
          <mat-icon>person_pin</mat-icon>
          {{ username }}
        </button>
        <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
          <a mat-menu-item [routerLink]="'/home'">
            <mat-icon>shopping_cart</mat-icon>
            Mis compras
          </a>
          <a mat-menu-item [routerLink]="'/login'">
            <mat-icon>person_off</mat-icon>
            Cerrar sesión
          </a>
        </mat-menu>
</div>
```